# an odd question about solving ODE by MATLAB

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

Why MATLAB sometimes cannot solve the relatively particular case but can solve the relatively general case?

For example:

[image]

I tried to input (x^2-1)*D2y + 0*x*Dy + 1*x*y = 0 in MATLAB and MATLAB still can't solve.

So I tried the cases of different integer values of a in MATLAB and the results are surprising:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

It seems that MATLAB can solve the cases of odd integers $a$ but can't solve the cases of even integers $a$, except for $a=2$, which is accidentally solved by [reduction of order](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Second-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquationSecondSolution.html).

Why MATLAB can solve the case of $a=2$ by [reduction of order](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Second-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquationSecondSolution.html) but not the cases of other even integers $a$? Can [reduction of order](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Second-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquationSecondSolution.html) in fact applicable for the cases of other even integers $a$? The usage of [reduction of order](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Second-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquationSecondSolution.html) has some limitations?

Answer (score 1):

Because in some older version of `MATLAB`, the symbolic toolbox uses `Maple` kernel to perform the symbolic integration/differention, or directly returns some built-in solution included in `Maple`. In your case, please refer to: [HeunC - The Heun Confluent function](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=HeunC) in `Maple`. Keep in mind that the semantics of your first command is somewhat ambiguous when passing to `Maple` due to lack of `varargin`-type input in this `Maple` function, in other words, you have to specify all the input to get a solution. In `MATLAB`, often something like `dsolve` calls other functions and uses `varargin` to pass unspecified number of parameters and inputs.

---

***A little rant:*** However, too bad `MATLAB` dropped `Maple` support around 2008 or 2009, and has been using something else ever since, here I couldn't test it on my laptop right now. This is what I got:
[image]

---

Anyway I suggest you try:

> `s = dsolve('(x^2-1)*D2y + 0*x*Dy + 1*x*y = 0','x')`

please keep me updated with what you got there.

Comment: Sorry about that the version of your MATLAB is too old.